# Prove that $L_p$-norm is non-convex, $p < 1$, $p \not = 0$.

Tags: convex-optimization, lp-spaces

How do I show that $$f (x) = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^p\right)^\frac{1}{p},\; p < 1,\; p \not = 0$$ is not convex? The hint is to use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $$\langle a, b\rangle \leq \|a\|_2\|b\|_2 .$$

Answer (score 0):

Pick concrete values for points $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$ and a scalar $\lambda \in [0,1]$.
Check if the definition of convexity holds for these values
(this requires you to calculate $f(x),f(y),f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda) y)$).
If this does not result in a contradiction to the definition of convexity, try other values and repeat.